# Как организовать скачивание файлов на своем сайте?

Tags: php, mvc

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать скачивание файлов со своего сайта. Используется схема MVC и при переходе по ссылке прямого скачивания http://site.ru/template/load/Catalog.pdf он у меня обращается к контроллеру кажется и выдает ошибку и ничего не скачивает, ошибка следующая:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to 
be a valid callback, class 'SiteController' does not have a method 'actionIndextsite' 
in /.../site.ru/components/Router.php on line 39
```

Как быть, как написать экшн для скачивания файла?

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в коде приложения.

В Router.php на строке 39 идет вызов метода actionIndextsite в классе SiteController, но такого метода в классе не существует. Возможно, ошибка написании метода (проверьте, может быть он называется actionIndexTSite, что больше соответствует стилю camelCase).

Comment: там нет ошибки, он говорит что нет метода экшна, точнее пути в роутах как я понимаю. мне нужно узнать как организовать скачивание файлов  через контроллер или не знаю как это все...

Comment: Если надо скачивать через контроллер, то в контроллере делайте так: 
1. Считывайте из request имя файла или, лучше, его id (а путь к файлу сохраняйте в БД). 
2. Читайте файл из файловой системы (сохраняете в переменную). 
3. Отправляете соответствующий типу файла заголовок Content-type. 
3. Выводите содержимое переменной, в которую считали файл. 

Все это требует определенной аккуратности. Вы должны подумать о безопасности, чтобы никто не мог загрузить условный /etc/password. А большой размер файлов может убить процесс, если превышен максимальный размер, указанный в php.ini в memory_limit.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью рабочий код...

```
$filename= ROOT . "/load/catalog.pdf";
$file_name="catalog.pdf";
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
header("Content-Disposition: filename=".$file_name);
readfile($filename);
```